# while assigning value to asp hidden field, escape character gets cleared

Tags: javascript, c#, json, string

I am following one strange issue.  Following is the detailed description

1. My object of JSON String

   ```
   public class ChartSearchCriteria
   {
   public ChartSearchCriteria()
   {

   }
   public DateTime StartDate
   {
       get;
       set;
   }
   public DateTime EndDate
   {
       get;
       set;
   }
   public Int32 ClassType
   {
       get;
       set;
   }
   public Int32 InstructorID
   {
       get;
       set;
   }            
   }
   ```
2. I am converting this object to JSON string and assigning to one hidden field

   ```
    ChartSearchCriteria objChartSearchCriteria = new ChartSearchCriteria()
       {
           StartDate = startDate,
           EndDate = endDate,
           ClassType = Convert.ToInt32(ddlClassType.SelectedValue)
       };
       string jsonSearchCriteria = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(objChartSearchCriteria);

       // Here in jsonSearchCriteria i am getting following string
       // "{\"StartDate\":\"\\/Date(1436466600000)\\/\",\"EndDate\":\"\\/Date(1439145000000)\\/\",\"ClassType\":0,\"InstructorID\":0}"
       hdnSearchData.Value = jsonSearchCriteria;
   ```
3. I want to pass this json string to another page with query string. I have used following javascript to get url

   ```
   alert(document.getElementById("hdnSearchData").value);
   // Here i am getting following JSON string from hidden field
   // {"StartDate":"\/Date(1436466600000)\/","EndDate":"\/Date(1439145000000)\/","ClassType":0,"InstructorID":0}
   var searchData = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("hdnSearchData").value);    
   var redirectUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_layouts/15/DetailedChart.aspx?searchdata=" + encodeURIComponen(JSON.stringify(searchData));
   ```
4. Now I have used following code to Deserialize that json string to object into another page where I have passed that json string as query string

   ```
       string jsonString = Convert.ToString(Page.Request.QueryString["searchdata"]);
       jsonString = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(jsonString);
       // Here I am getting following json string
       // {"StartDate":"\/Date(1436466600000)\/","EndDate":"\/Date(1439145000000)\/","ClassType":0,"InstructorID":0}
       JavaScriptSerializer oJS = new JavaScriptSerializer();
       ChartSearchCriteria oRootObject = new ChartSearchCriteria();
       oRootObject = oJS.Deserialize<ChartSearchCriteria>(jsonString);
   ```

So here i am getting exception like:

> "Date(234234000)" cannot be converted to date time when Deserializing json string to object

The only thing which I get is that while assigning to json string to hidden field, It is losing escape character from json.

JSON String created from server side :

> {\"StartDate\":\"\/Date(1436466600000)\/\",\"EndDate\":\"\/Date(1439145000000)\/\",\"ClassType\":0,\"InstructorID\":0}"

JSON string gotten from client side using javascript:

> {"StartDate":"/Date(1436466600000)/","EndDate":"/Date(1439145000000)/","ClassType":0,"InstructorID":0}

So you can see above both different string which shows while assigning json string to hidden field , it is removing escape characters and that's why I cannot convert it back to object into another page.

I am sure 100% that it is issue related to escape character because i have checked deserialize method with following string and it is working fine

> {\"StartDate\":\"\/Date(1436466600000)\/\",\"EndDate\":\"\/Date(1439145000000)\/\",\"ClassType\":0,\"InstructorID\":0}"

So how can I resolve that issue? My final goal is to pass json string to another page and deserializing into same object.

Any help will be highly appreciated and let me know anyone want some more information on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved issue by using following code.

```
 string jsonString = Convert.ToString(Page.Request.QueryString["searchdata"]);
jsonString = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(jsonString);
// Here I am getting following json string
// {"StartDate":"\/Date(1436466600000)\/","EndDate":"\/Date(1439145000000)\/","ClassType":0,"InstructorID":0}
// By using following line I have corrected json string and now it is being deserialized to object.
jsonString = jsonString.Replace("/", "\\/");
JavaScriptSerializer oJS = new JavaScriptSerializer();
ChartSearchCriteria oRootObject = new ChartSearchCriteria();
oRootObject = oJS.Deserialize<ChartSearchCriteria>(jsonString);
```